# How to parse a Mbox file with JavaMail API?

Tags: parsing, jakarta-mail, java, mbox

I want to use JavaMail to parse an .mbox file just like this one http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-java-user/201210.mbox.

What I thought of doing was:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
Store store = session.getStore("Here should go the .mbox file");
store.connect();

Folder folder = store.getFolder(server);
folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
...
```

Which proved wrong. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thank you in advance.

**Update: Working example**

```
public class MBoxFileReader implements MessageReader {
    private final Path path;  // Path to .mbox file

    public MBoxFileReader(Path path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    @Override
    public Message[] readMessages() {
        Message[] messages = new Message[0];
        URLName server = new URLName("mbox:" + path.toString());
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.mime.address.strict", "false");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        try {
            Folder folder = session.getFolder(server);
            folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            messages = folder.getMessages();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return messages;
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not get your code to work. For example, I was unable to resolve the MessageReader in any javax mail API. Removing the "implements MessageReader" from the code and using the code without it (which did compile), I got a "no such provider for mbox" Exception.

Comment: @Morkus As Bill suggested,  you need to build JavaMail mbox store and import it in your project

Comment: OK. I was looking for something that would read a regular MBOX file as from MacMail, for example. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [JavaMail mbox Store](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Mbox-Store), but you'll need to build it yourself.

Comment: Thank you @Bill, it works well. Although it took quite a bit time and plenty of errors till I built it, because I was unfamiliar with maven. The truth is that an error still exists while building using the eclipse plugin for maven, but everything seems fine when I use the mbox.jar file in my project.

Comment: @Xipo were you able to use mbox jar? can you please give me sample code implementation? I am not able to see how to read my mbox file using java mail mbox jar.

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you successfully build the mbox provider yourself?

Comment: @VikramGulia I added a code snippet in the question showing how to get the messages

Comment: @BillShannon yeah, i was able to build the jar for MBOX successfully. thanks I will check it out.

Comment: @BillShannon When I try to build using directions from your link, I get the following error: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sun.mail:libmbox:so:1.6.1: Could not find artifact com.sun.mail:mbox:jar:1.6.1 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2).  I can't seem to find libmbox either.. has it been moved?

Comment: Neither of these are published to Maven central, you have to build them locally.  Exactly what did you do to build them and exactly what output did you get?  Send the details in email to javamail_ww@oracle.com if that's easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with Apache Mime4j:

```
    CharsetEncoder ENCODER = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder();
    final File mbox = new File(mboxPath);

    for (CharBufferWrapper message : MboxIterator.fromFile(mbox).charset(ENCODER.charset()).build()) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
```

you'll need:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-mime4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Interesting. I tried this, but in every case pointing to an mbox file I got a Operation Not Permitted Exception. (note: that you have to download separately the MboxIterator and a couple other classes before this code will compile).